# What is best way to compare each item in large collection to each other with condition in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a very large collection with around 8 millions record each week and I need analyze them to find related items and compile a report.

Log Object

```
_id:
user_id: int
created_date: date
created_at: datetime
event_id: string
market_data: dict
```

I need to find all object belong to user in a day and find related for each object with same event_id and in range +/- 5 seconds, compare their market_data.

Sample code:

```
var matched_selection = [];

db.selection.find({user_id: _main_id_, date: _date_}).forEach(
  function(main_selection){
    db.selection.find({
      user_id: {$ne: _main_id_},
      event_id: main_selection.event_id,
      created_at: {
        $gte: main_selection.created_at-5000,
        $lte: main_selection.created_at+5000
      }
    }).foreach(
      function(sub_selection){
        // compare main_selection.market_data to sub_selection.market_data
        // and put result to matched_selection array
      }
    )
})
```

In the past I queried and compared in the client. But the performance was terrible because of the large amount of data transferred between client and server.

Currently I write a server-side javascript to compare data and only return the result - it is clearly faster - but server side javascript will be deprecated soon.

Now i try to use map/reduce but sub query (the one to find sub_selection) in map functions are not allowed.

What is the best approach in my case?

Comment: @markus: really sub query allowed in map/reduce function? I can't event access 'db' object.

Comment: I didn't answer the question, I just tried to mak the question and the code more readable.